# How can I verify the percentage?

Tags: python, list

```
cars = ('coupe', 'coupe', 'coupe', 'carbiolet', 'sedan')
x = cars.count("coupe")
y = len(cars)
```

Q: If the number of times the coupe element appears in the tuple cars is more than 45%, print "Too many." to the terminal. If not, print "You are set."

that means
if x/y > 45%;     I will have to print "Too many" else "You are set".

But I can't run it in the python program.
Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

45% is the same as 45/100, that is, 0.45. So you could write:

```
>>> cars = ('coupe', 'coupe', 'coupe', 'carbiolet', 'sedan')
>>> x = cars.count("coupe")
>>> y = len(cars)
>>> x
3   
>>> y
5   
>>> threshold = 0.45 # 45% or you could also write 'threshold = 45/100'
>>> if x/y > threshold:
...     print("Too many")
... else:
...     print("You are set")
... 
Too many
```

Answer (score 1):

You already close to find out, just use if statement to check percentage.

You can do that as follows:

```
cars = ('coupe', 'coupe', 'coupe', 'carbiolet', 'sedan')
x = cars.count("coupe")
y = len(cars)

stat = 0.45 # %45
if x/y > stat:
 print("Too many")
else:
 print("You are set")
```

Comment: This seems to be the best answer